# How to cast to string the result of an inner query?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following query (which should return a scalar/numeric), But I still get a sql error.

I am using mysql 5.0.77 or 5.1.37

`SELECT CAST(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 AS VARCHAR)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast to `VARCHAR`. Try `CHAR(n)` instead:

```
SELECT CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1) AS CHAR(10))
```

A list of the types you can cast to can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT CAST(t.x AS VARCHAR) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS x FROM t1) t;` should work

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR) FROM t1
```

Comment: I have simplified the problem, But I do need this as an inner query.